# NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest seems to hang

Tags: ios, objective-c

This HTTP call seems to be hanging and I can't see why. The logging line after the call never runs.

I'm almost certainly doing something extremely stupid, but if anyone can spot what it is I'd be grateful. As far as I can see my code is equivalent to the docs.

It doesn't seem to matter what URL I use, and the HTTP request is never logged by the server (if pointed at one).

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

NSURLResponse *res = nil;
NSError *err = nil;

NSLog(@"About to send req %@",req.URL);

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:&err];

NSLog(@"this never runs");
```

Any ideas?

**Update**

Thanks to everyone who's posted so far. Still seeing the problem. A bit more detail:

- The code is being tested on the device
- Other HTTP calls work fine so if it's a network problem it's a non-trivial one
- The code has hung well past the normal timeout. I know it hangs for over 20 minutes. I killed it at that point, but I assume it would continue to hang.
- I'm not currently using a delegate and don't plan to, see below.
- In other places in the app I use `sendAynchronousRequest` but in this instance I need to pass a return value (and I'm not on the main thread), so `sendSynchronousRequest` is the only option I know of.
- In case it matters, the context is that I'm implementing the `NSURLCache` protocol, specifically the `cachedResponseForRequest` method, which requires I return a `NSCachedURLResponse`

Comment: Did you see this in the reference? "Because this call can potentially take several minutes to fail (particularly when using a cellular network in iOS), you should never call this function from the main thread of a GUI application."

Comment: Did you implement the delegate methods of `NSURLConnection`? As some of them are rather important. Like `didFailWithError:` or `didRecieveData:`.

Comment: It is true, as said in the comments and answers, that `sendSynchronousRequest:` blocks the main thread. But this does *not explain* why this method should hang *forever*, as claimed in the question. There must be some other problem. (And your code works in my simulator in less than one second.)

Comment: I would like to know how long the OP waited before giving up.  It's an important factor.

Comment: @doge: `sendSynchronousRequest:` does not use delegate methods.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for clarifying. I did not know that, i only assumed it did since it uses `NSURLConnection`.

Comment: I ran the code. It worked fine.

Comment: I waited various different times. Current wait is over 5 minutes. I'm on a wifi connection, and still see the hang with my local dev server. Currently looking at my delegate declaration as that seems like the most likely candidate. Thanks everybody.

Comment: So you have assigned a delegate to the `NSURLConnection` object?  Another important detail missing from the question.

Comment: @RichardMarr: What delegate declaration? `sendSynchronousRequest:` does not use delegate methods. Does the problem occur on the device or simulator?

Comment: @MartinR yep, I realised that after commenting and staring blankly at XCode for a moment. Problem occurs on the device.

Comment: @RichardMarr did you figure this out? I'm also trying to send a NSURLConnection in the cachedResponseForRequest method. I'm also hanging. I see that you're using the webview proxy, but that doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: @kevinl no I didn't solve it. Given that the same code works fine when run in other contexts I suspect something about `cachedResponseForRequest` is causing an error that my code didn't pick up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works in other contexts so it's clear that it's happening because the call is being made from the `cachedResponseForRequest` method of an `NSURLCache`. Running it elsewhere works fine.

Since this was intended to enable a proxy between AJAX calls in an embedded `UIWebView` and the server (for the purpose of not having to rewrite API request signing code in JS) I've worked around it using [Marcus Westin's WebViewProxy class](https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewProxy) which works a treat.

Comment: this is not a generic solution for all users who have this problem. This is a problem irrespective of having web views or not. You should accept generic answer to your question. Down voting

Comment: @KunalBalani sure, and if someone posts one I'll accept it. Since it's been 2 years since I posted this question I'm not holding out much hope

Answer (score 7):

Run the request in a background queue so it does not block the main thread where UI updates occur:

```
 dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);

    // execute a task on that queue asynchronously
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/"]];

NSURLResponse *res = nil;
NSError *err = nil;

NSLog(@"About to send req %@",req.URL);

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&res error:&err];

    });
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not on the main thread and I need it to be synchronous.

Comment: @NikosM. - Wouldn't it be better to use the inbuilt `sendAsynchronousRequest` ?

Comment: Yes the better solution is asynchronous request, but as he mentioned he need it to be synchronous.

Comment: Thanks guys. By need it to be synchronous I mean it needs to block the thread it's running in, in order to be able to return the data type that the protocol I'm dealing with is expecting. `dispatch_async` doesn't help me do that.

Comment: Not clear on what you mean. My method needs to return data from the request, so using a handler wouldn't work unless it was wrapped in something that blocked the thread. Using a promise would work, but I should just be able to make a synchronous HTTP request, and haven't yet come across a reason that it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

Add delegate `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>`

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your string here"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];//It will start delegates


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [received_data setLength:0];//Set your data to 0 to clear your buffer 
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [received_data appendData:data];//Append the download data..
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //Use your downloaded data here
}
```

This method more better to download data.. It wont use main thread so the app wont hang.. I hope it will be more useful for you

Comment: Thanks @TamilKing, I've elaborated a bit above on the details of my problem in case you can shed any further light.

Answer (score -1):

When your request succeeds with the response then your NSLog will execute because sendSynchronousRequest method works on main thread.

Answer (score -2):

Its a `synchronous` method - i.e. it runs on the **main thread**. Therefore, your application will hang - and it'll wait till the data is downloaded.

To prevent it: use the `sendAsynchronousRequest` method. It'll run this process on a background thread and won't disrupt your application or simply - won't make it *hang*.

Here's how to use `sendAsynchronousRequest`:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_URL_HERE"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
{
    //the NSData in the completion handler is where your data is downloaded.
}];
```

---

Considering all the circumstances, I think that the problem exists due to your delegate declaration. So declare `<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>` and the declare an `NSMutableData` : `myData` object and an `NSURLConnection` : `urlConnection` as properties. Now use this :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLwithString : @"YOUR_URL_HERE"];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
*urlConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    [myData setLength:0]; 
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{

    [myData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //You can use the complete downloaded data - NSMutableData here.
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to know why it *never* returns, not why it blocks the main thread...

Comment: Yep, @trojanfoe is correct. Thanks for the answer but it doesn't address my problem. I need to stay synchronous in this context.

Comment: @RichardMarr - Your code worked fine on mine. Maybe you have some networking issues on your system.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag thanks for trying. I suspect the answer isn't a networking issue as other (async) calls work just fine. I need this one to be synchronous but it's hanging.

Comment: @RichardMarr - Then the problem is definitely there with your delegate declaration. I'll update my answer. Just wait a min.

Comment: @RichardMarr - Please have a look at my answer now.

Comment: Thanks @SanjeetSuhag, I'm still trying to figure out why `sendSynchronousRequest` isn't returning before trying another approach. As I added in an update above, I need to pass a specific return value so using a delegate, asynchronous call, or dispatch queue will make that difficult.